# Starting Screen with a Command

Tags: java, gnu-screen, minecraft

I need to be able to start up a screen without connecting to it, but it also needs to run my start.sh script which contains the java line to start Minecraft.

```
screen -d -m new3 -c start.sh
```

Is what I've been trying to use, but it never runs start.sh

In a snippet of code I found on line it seems to do what I want but I need some help

```
 mc_start() {
    cd $MCPATH
    as_user "cd $MCPATH && screen -dmS $SCREEN $INVOCATION"
    #
    # Waiting for the server to start
    #
    seconds=0
    until ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -v -i SCREEN | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
    do
        sleep 1 
        seconds=$seconds+1
        if [[ $seconds -eq 5 ]]
        then
            echo "Still not running, waiting a while longer..."
        fi
        if [[ $seconds -ge 120 ]]
        then
            echo "Failed to start, aborting."
            exit 1
        fi
    done    
    echo "$SERVICE is running."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because your command is wrong. I'm assuming that you want to create a new session named `new3` and detach from that

```
screen -d -m -S new3 ~/start.sh
```

Afterwards you can run the following command to connect back to your session.

```
screen -R new3
```

Comment: I tried that, and it says there is no screen by that name created

Comment: Even with your updated post, still no screen is being created

Comment: Is your start.sh script terminating? That will cause the session to go away. Maybe put something that will prompt for user input before quitting?

Comment: That's the odd thing, because my script is simply, java -Xmx512M -Xms512M -jar craftbukkit.jar nogui
Which should start minecraft, and when you run minecraft, it stays running in a console like manner

Comment: Yeah I'm stumpted, maybe you can try with the -L option to log any console output to a screen.x file. Maybe that'll give you some clue what's going on?

Comment: I just eddited the code with a script I found online, can I use a similar method?

Comment: Hmmmm putting what was inside the start.sh directly into the command line worked!